# Power BI: distinct count

Tags: count, powerbi, measure

I have a table Import in PowerBi of which I want to count the number of sheets per File.
How do I make a measure that counts the number of sheets per file?

| ColumnX | ColumnY | FileName | SheetName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | File1 | Sheet1 |
| a | b | File1 | Sheet2 |
| c | d | File1 | Sheet3 |
| a | b | File2 | Sheet1 |
| a | b | File2 | Sheet2 |

How do I get this result?

| File | NumberOfSheets |
| --- | --- |
| File1 | 3 |
| File2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measure can be like this:

```
NumberOfSheets = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[SheetName] )
```

In a new table visual, add your `FileName` column and this new `NumberOfSheets` measure to produce your desired result.

However, for the `Total` row, this only counts the distinct number of sheet name variations in your table. If you want the total number of sheets to be displayed in the `Total` row, you can change your formula to something else, like this:

```
NumberOfSheets (Total Sum) = 
SUMX ( 
    VALUES ( 'Table'[FileName] ) , 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[SheetName] )
)
```

Here are the results:

[image]

**Another edit:**

If your data table is known to have 1 row per sheet, you can easily just count rows instead:

```
NumberOfSheets (Simple) = COUNTROWS ( 'Table' )
```

But this depends entirely on the full data table. If this assumption holds true, there is no reason to use anything other than the `COUNTROWS` approach, since this is probably the faster calculation.